# laravel9 middleware not loaded when frontend and admin are seperated

Tags: laravel

I am doing the separation of frontend and admin. After several days of studying, It seems ok now. My github:  https://github.com/ronrun/laravel-multiauth
Currently there are 4 versions.
There are 3 branches, the branch 9.x_two-tables has two version.

commit: frontend and admin login can login separately
The structure:

```
app\Http\Controller\Admin\Auth\LoginController.php
app\Http\Controller\Admin\DashboardController.php  
app\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController.php
app\Http\Controller\HomeController.php
```

commit: more seperation!

```
app\Admin\Console
app\Admin\Exceptions
app\Admin\Http\Controllers
app\Admin\Http\Middleware
app\Admin\Providers
app\Frontend\Console
app\Frontend\Exceptions
app\Frontend\Http\Controllers
app\Frontend\Http\Middleware
app\Frontend\Providers
app\Models
```

In short, it's

```
app\Admin
app\Frontend
app\Models
```

During the studying process, lots of questions I want to ask. Now all seems working fine. But I still have questions about the final commit: more seperation!

**Question: Many files inside app\Frontend not loaded, only app\Admin's files are used.**
The two files:

```
app\Admin\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php
app\Frontend\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php
```

I expected that when I am not logged in, but visite a page should login, the Authenticate's redirectTo() should do the redirect work. But only Admin's Authenticate.php is loaded. I clear the content of Frontend's Authenticate.php, make it compeletly empty, NO ERRORS. But If I clear the content of Admin's Authenticate.php, it says this class cannot found.

I found the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php is the same. **Then I delete frontend's middleware folder, still working fine, no errors.**

Then I delete app\Frontend\Console, Exceptions, no errors. The login functions of Frontend and Admin both working. But app\Frontend\Providers cannot be deleted, or error shows.

bootstrap\app.php

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Frontend\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Frontend\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Frontend\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Admin\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Admin\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Admin\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

Why does it only loads files inside app\Admin ?
Why no errors, login logout functions still work, when many Frontend files are deleted?

Any suggestions to improve the codes, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: could you add some code from your middlewares?

Comment: I dont know what you mean? I wrote codes in Frontend and Admin middleware, but only Admin ones work.

Comment: ahh sprry I see you have the code of the whole github projet!

Comment: In `bootstrap/app.php` the bindings for same contracts(interfaces) are defined twice so the last one overwrites the earlier - means all **Admin** bindings override the ones for **Frontend** defined earlier. Hence only **app/Admin** files (middleware) are used. What exactly are  you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make a project that seperate frontend and admin, and uses two tables. I'll do more in the feature like languages, products.... Now I want to keep the necessary files, delete files not needed. make the structure reasonable. But I have to make sure.

Comment: Donkarnash, maybe your comment is the direct answer. But why? They have different namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the **frontend** and **admin** separate, basically need:

- separate routes file (say web.php, api.php & admin.php)
- separate redirectTo routes in **RedirectIfAuthenticated**
- separate redirectTo routes in **Authenticate**

To achieve that keep all default middleware & providers under `app` folder -

```
|-app
    |-Http
        |-Middleware
            -Authenticate.php
            -EncryptCookies.php
            -PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php
            -RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
            -TrimStrings.php
            -TrustHosts.php
            -TrustProxies.php
            -VerifyCsrfToken.php
    |-Providers
        -AppServiceProvider.php
        -AuthServiceProvider.php
        -BroadcastServiceProvider.php
        -EventServiceProvider.php
        -RouteServiceProvider.php
    |-Frontend
        |-Http
            |-Controllers
                |-FrontendControllers
            |-Middleware
                |-FrontendSpecificMiddleware (if any)
            |-Requests
                |-FrontendFormRequests (if any)
        |-Languages
        |-Other
    |-Admin
        |-Http
            |-Controllers
                |-AdminControllers
            |-Middleware
                |-AdminSpecificMiddleware (if any)
            |-Requests
                |-AdminFormRequests (if any)
        |-Languages
        |-Other
        |-routes
            |-web.php
```

To load routes, in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`

```php
    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->prefix('admin')
            ->as('admin.')
            ->group(app_path('Admin/routes/web.php'));
    });
```

To set the redirect route for successful authentication

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                $prefix = $request->route()->getPrefix();
                return $prefix == '/admin' ? redirect(route('admin.home') : redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

To set redirect route for unsuccessful authentication

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
                $prefix = $request->route()->getPrefix();
                return $prefix == '/admin' ? route('admin.login') : route('login);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also have `App\Frontend\FrontendServiceProvider` and `App\Admin\AdminServiceProvider` if you want and register them under `providers` array in `config/app.php`

To summarise, take cue from **Domain Driven Design (DDD)** approach. You can read about **DDD** at:

[Stitcher - Laravel Beyond Crud - Domain Oriented Laravel](https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-beyond-crud-01-domain-oriented-laravel)

[Conciliating Laravel and DDD](https://lorisleiva.com/conciliating-laravel-and-ddd)

Comment: Excellent。I will try what you said. Then tell you the result. Thank you.